# How Many Possible Addition Equations Can Make a Certain Sum?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, integer-partitions

To jump right into the rawness of my topic, how many addition expressions create a certain sum?

Like, for example, if $n = 3$, a formula would return $4$, because the possible addition equations with a sum of $n$ are (with only whole numbers) $1+2$, $2+1$, $3+0$, and $0+3$, which means there are four possible equations with a sum of $n$. Is there a formula for this?

Comment: You’re talking about [Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Comment: @Tavish, Thank You! That explains everything.

Comment: It is not quite partitions, because there, say, $3+0$ and $0+3$ only count as one - as $3$. So $p(3)=3$, and the three partitions are $3$, $1+2$ and $1+1+1$. And for the partition function $p(n)$ as above there is indeed a formula.

Comment: To emphasize, you need to elaborate on how many summands (*how many terms being added*) are allowed, whether any of the summands are allowed to be zero, whether any of the summands are allowed to be repeated, and whether order of summands matters.  Your examples were limited to exactly two distinct possibly zero summands however it is not clear if this was intended.

Comment: For instance, with $n=6$ would each of the following be allowed and be considered distinct?  $3+3, 2+2+2, 3+3+0, 1+1+1+1+2, 1+2+1+1+1, 3+3+0+0+0+0+\dots+0+\dots$ And if any are not allowed, why specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order matters and $0$ is allowed, so $0+3$ and $3+0$ both count, you are talking about [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).  For weak compositions into two parts there are $n+1$ of them.  The first number ranges from $0$ through $n$ and the other is what is left.